# Changing default css in Angular Material for md-input

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have implemented form using angualr-material, I can't find any standard ways to change default color coding in material.

form

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 testFormLabel">
                <md-input-container class="testLabel">
                    <label>Reason</label>
                        <input name="reasonBox" id="reasonBox" ng-model="obj. reasonBox" ng-required="true">  
                </md-input-container>
    </div>
```

css

```
.md-input-has-value. testLabel > input {
    color:#008cba;      
}
```

**Problem**

How can i change auto focus label name and underline to different color ( let say from dark blue to green )

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this selector to change the input:

```
md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid).md-input-focused .md-input {
    border-color: red
}
```

Use this to change the label:

```
md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid).md-input-focused label {
    color: red
}
```

Include this after you include the css for angular material.

I got this by going to the docs page here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

Looking at their demo, and inspecting a focused input.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i couldn't change the label color from blue.

Comment: Why not? Inspect the page and see why this rule isn't being accepted.

Comment: it is but border-color applies to the underline not to the label.

Comment: Edited answer with label coloring technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `<md-input-container [dividerColor]="primary|accent|warn">` to set the color when the field is in focus.

[From the docs...](https://material.angular.io/components/component/input)

> The divider (line under the input content) color can be changed by using the dividerColor attribute of md-input-container. A value of primary is the default and will correspond to the theme primary color. Alternatively, accent or warn can be specified to use the theme's accent or warn color.

Comment: Just for clarification, this answer is about Angular2+, but the OP asked about AngularJS (version 1).