# Change the cursor and remove underlying line

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

```
<div class="clientxxx-table-field">
    <div    id="client-table" 
            *ngIf="displayedColumnsOfClient != null && dataSourceOfClient != null" 
            class="table-container mat-elevation-z8 verticalScrollableParent" 
            [style.max-height.px]="'400'">
        <div class="FilterAndFilterUsed  client-header">
            <div class="table-name">Client</div>
            <mat-form-field class="filter">
                <input  class="filter-input" 
                        matInput (keyup)="leftTableFilter($event.target.value)">
                <mat-placeholder class="placeholder">Filter</mat-placeholder>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-slide-toggle   class="FilterUsed" 
                                (change)="leftFilterUsed($event)">
                Used
            </mat-slide-toggle>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a `mat-form-field` identified by the class `filter`.
I am trying to make the font cursor "white" and the blue line that appears when the element is on focus disappear.
The changes should apply only for to the input field in the elements with class "filter".

I have found some references ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166078/changing-default-css-in-angular-material-for-md-input)) but things in material change often so I am a little lost.

[image]

---

```
  .filter 
    input 
      caret-color: white;
    .mat-focused .mat-form-field-underline 
      display: none;
```

The cursor (caret) is not white but the `.mat-form-field-underline` / `.mat-form-field-ripple` is still there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go - [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbxmsj?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.css)

```
::ng-deep .filter  {
  background: green;
}

::ng-deep .filter.mat-focused .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}

::ng-deep .filter input {
  caret-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the caret color with the `caret-color` style. As for the blue line under the input, you'll need to hide `.mat-form-field-ripple` which appears when the `mat-form-field` has focus.

```
.filter input {
  caret-color: white;
}

.filter.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
  display: none;
}
```